# Using the Bing Spell Check API to correct user inputted text containing names which may be from other languages

Tags: c#, rest, locale, bing

I'm having a hard time getting the the Bing Spell Check API to return the 'special' characters which may be in the names of people from non-English speaking countries.

For example, if a English speaking user inputted the name "Diego Brandao", I would expect a response from Bing of "Diego Brandão".  Furthermore, if a user inputted "Diego Brandão", I would expect no corrections from Bing.

This is a minimal implementation of the Bing Spell Check API where I input a name:

```
class BingSpellCheck
{

    private const string apiKey1 = "my key1";
    private const string apiKey2 = "my key2";
    private const string endpoint = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck";

    private static TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string name = "Diego Brandão";
        string name = "Diego Brandao";

        JEnumerable<JToken> results = QueryBing(name);

        List<BingSpellCheckDTO> tokens = new List<BingSpellCheckDTO>();
        foreach (JToken result in results)
        {
            BingSpellCheckDTO token = result.ToObject<BingSpellCheckDTO>();
            tokens.Add(token);
        }

        foreach (BingSpellCheckDTO token in tokens)
        {
            name = name.Replace(token.token, token.suggestions[0].suggestion);
        }

        name = textInfo.ToTitleCase(name);

        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    private static JEnumerable<JToken> QueryBing(string fighter)
    {
        string uri = GenerateRequestUri(fighter);
        string response = SendRequestAsync(uri).Result;

        JObject json = JObject.Parse(response);

        JEnumerable<JToken> results;

        try
        {
            results = json["flaggedTokens"].Children();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            QueryBing(fighter);
        }

        return results;
    }


    private static string GenerateRequestUri(string text)
    {
        string requestUri = endpoint;
        requestUri += string.Format("?text={0}", text);
        requestUri += "&mode=spell";
        return requestUri;
    }


    private static async Task<string> SendRequestAsync(string url)
    {
        string response_string = null;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey1);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us, en;q=0.8, pt-br;q=0.7, es-mx;q=0.7");
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            response_string = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            response.Dispose();
        }

        return response_string;
    }

}

class BingSpellCheckDTO
{
    public int offset { get; set; }

    public string token { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }

    public List<Suggestion> suggestions { get; set; }
}

class Suggestion
{
    public string suggestion { get; set; }

    public float score { get; set; }
}
```

I apologize for the long block of code, but it's fairly straight forward.

Please play particular attention to the line `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us, en;q=0.8, pt-br;q=0.7, es-mx;q=0.7");`.  This defines a request header which specifies a list of acceptable languages for the response to include.  This doesn't appear to have any effect, so I think I must be doing this part wrong.

As of right now the input of "Diego Brandao" doesn't produce any corrections, but I want for this to be corrected to "Diego Brandão".  The input of "Diego Brandão" is corrected to "Diego Brando", but I don't want for this produce any corrections.

This is a Brazilian Portuguese name, and I have tried to specify in the request header to accept Brazilian Portuguese.

Here is a description of the "Accept-Language" header: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Here is some Bing API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-spell-check-api-v5-reference

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solved this?

Comment: @UdiIdan  Not exactly. I had remove the Bing API due to no longer having access to a valid API key. I ended up searching Wikipedia, and getting the top 10 results, and then picking the result that had the smallest [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) from the user inputted string. Sorry I can't be of more help.